# How to continue a git merge where someone pushed by marking all files as "resolved"?

Tags: git, diff, git-merge

My friend

- run `git merge master`
- resolved some of the conflicts
- marked all of the files as "resolved"
- pushed the merge commit to a temp branch

I pulled the branch. I can see diff lines in the files like

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
text1
=======
text2
>>>>>>> origin/master
```

How can I simulate the merge where my friend left off?

I am ok with the solutions which include some pull/checkouts into other places, some copy/paste commands, other commands/tools to detect diff parts etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not try to recover from your friend's work, but rather redo the merge from scratch.

Find your friend's merged commit and use `git log --graph` or `git log --format=fuller` to determine its parent commits:

E.g., I have `39184c481a` which is a merge of `2aa69455a3` into `1d3c2f45f6`.

```
git log --format=fuller 39184c481a

commit 39184c481a
Merge: 1d3c2f45f6 2aa69455a3
Author: ...
```

Then checkout the original first parent and merge the other parent into it

```
git checkout 1d3c2f45f6
git merge 2aa69455a3
```

and now I'm in the same state I was when the commit was done. So from here you should be able to redo the conflict resolution.

You probably want to give yourself a branch to be able to find this work later:

```
git checkout -b dev.fixing-the-merge
```

And eventually merge this back into your main branch, or possibly rewrite the history with a `git push --force` if your team is willing to let you do that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can `git grep '<<<<<<<'` through the code to find those places, which still need to be merged. If you corrected the code, you can either commit this on your own to indicate which resolution was done by which author, or you can amend to the existing commit to have each commit buildable and correct. However, in this case author information on the commits are less informative.

You have to consider your git organization tool too. On github commits to branches are often forbidden. Therefore force-pushing an updated commit is often not possible. In this case you have to create your own commit. On Gerrit amending to commits is part of the design, which updated open changes.

Answer (score 1):

I combined this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54099010/2900777 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54104467/2900777.

- Pull the branch into a directory (`BRANCH_DIR`)
- Simulate the same merge in another directory (`MERGE_DIR`)
- In `BRANCH_DIR`,  run the command below and sort the files you need to check

  ```
  git grep '<<<<<<<' | cut -d':' -f1 | sort -u
  ```
- In `MERGE_DIR`, for each file in the previous step, run

  ```
  git mergetool FILENAME
  ```
- After resolving conflicts in the file in `MERGE_DIR`, copy/paste the content into the file in the `BRANCH_DIR`
- Create a new commit or amend the previous one. (It depends on your use case)